# neo4j don't start after load a .dump file

Tags: neo4j, database, nosql

I dumped my graph.db with this command in terminal:
    `sudo neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=/home/user/graphdb.dump`

then I loaded graphdb.dump in another computer with this command in terminal:
    `sudo neo4j-admin load --from=/home/user/graphdb.dump --database=graph.db --force`

Now when I start neo4j with the command:
    `sudo service neo4j start` 
it doesn't start.

When I uninstall neo4j with these commands:
    `apt-get purge neo4j`
    `sudo apt-get autoremove`

and install it again with the command:
    `sudo apt install neo4j`
loaded database starts correctly.

How can I dump and load my database in neo4j?

Comment: What Linux user did you use to run the "neo4j-admin dump/load" command ? If it wasn't the neo4j user ... that is very likely the reason the database didn't start.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? How can I become neo4j user?

Comment: The problem is that when using the package installs (apt in your case), the software and database is installed with user "neo4j". If you run "sudo neo4j-admin", you're running things as root and the resulting files will have root as owner (instead of neo4j). So you should run it as "sudo -u neo4j neo4j-admin". Check the permissions of everything under /var/lib/neo4j. It should be neo4j:adm for everything. If not ... that's the reason the database does not start.

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, i have similar problem here but i am doing it from windows machine. what would be windows equivalent command for it?

Comment: You can use WSL to type Linux commands on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that the Neo4j versions installed match in two computers. I had the same problem in which dump file was created in version 3.3.5 and the machine I tried to load the dump file had 3.2.11. It didn't give any errors in the logs files and no errors while starting the service. However the service stopped immediately every time I tried to restart. Then I figured two versions were not compatible.